# python マルチプロセスで temporary directory が時々みえなくなる謎

Tags: python

python で temp directory を作ってその中にいろいろ中間結果を出力してるんですが
これをマルチプロセス化したところ子プロセスで temp directory が見つからない謎な現象に遭遇しました
毎回ではなく時々 False になります

原因わかる方いらっしゃいますでしょうか

再現する最小単位まで削ったコード

```
import tempfile
import os
import sys
import time

def main():
  global tmp_dir

  # tmpdir 作成
  tmp_dir_obj = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
  tmp_dir = tmp_dir_obj.name
  print(tmp_dir)
  print(os.path.exists(tmp_dir))

  n_process = 4

  # プロセスを４つ作る
  pids = list(range(n_process))
  for i in range(n_process):
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid:  # 親プロセスは子プロセスIDを記憶して続行
      pids[i] = pid

    else:  # 子プロセスは start をよんで終了
      start()
      sys.exit()

  # ここからは親のみ

  # 子プロセスを全部まつ
  print('#wait pid')
  print(pids)
  for pid in pids:
    os.waitpid(pid, 0)
    print(f'join {pid}')

  # メッセージ表示して temp 削除
  print('#tmp clean')
  tmp_dir_obj.cleanup()


def start():
  time.sleep(1)
  # tmp_dir があるか確認
  print(tmp_dir)
  print(os.path.exists(tmp_dir))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

実行結果

```
# python tmp_dir_test.py
/var/folders/4t/ktwsj9q134l5dry9p2xpwfnh0000gq/T/tmpi1xjdjac
True
#wait pid
[28132, 28133, 28134, 28135]
/var/folders/4t/ktwsj9q134l5dry9p2xpwfnh0000gq/T/tmpi1xjdjac
True
/var/folders/4t/ktwsj9q134l5dry9p2xpwfnh0000gq/T/tmpi1xjdjac
False
/var/folders/4t/ktwsj9q134l5dry9p2xpwfnh0000gq/T/tmpi1xjdjac
False
/var/folders/4t/ktwsj9q134l5dry9p2xpwfnh0000gq/T/tmpi1xjdjac
False
join 28132
join 28133
join 28134
join 28135
#tmp clean
```

---

OS は Mac
Python 3.9.0 です

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> python で temp directory を作ってその中にいろいろ中間結果を出力してるんですが
> これをマルチプロセス化したところ子プロセスで temp directory が見つからない謎な現象に遭遇しました 毎回ではなく時々
> False になります

生成するプロセス数を増やすと現象の再現性が高くなります。
こちらの環境(※)で実行したところ、`n_process = 8`の場合、5プロセス目以降でほぼ確実に`os.path.exists(tmp_dir)`がFalseになります。

※　確認した環境は以下です。

- Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- Python 3.9.5

> 原因わかる方いらっしゃいますでしょうか

straceで確認したところ、最初に子プロセスが終了した時点でディレクトリが削除されていました。
生成したプロセスの終了を待ち合わせている処理である

```
os.waitpid(pid, 0)
```

の直後にディレクトリは存在していませんでした。
`tmp_dir_obj.cleanup()`が実行される前にディレクトリは削除されています。

---

https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/tempfile.html
によると、
「コンテキストの完了または一時ディレクトリオブジェクトの破棄により、新しく作成された一時ディレクトリとそのすべてのコンテンツがファイルシステムから削除される。」とあります。

最初にプロセスが終了した時点で「一時ディレクトリオブジェクトの破棄」が行われ、ディレクトリが削除されたのだと思います。

Comment: 確かに親の cleanup 前に存在確認をいれてみたところすでに存在しなかったです。
waitpid がうまく動いてなくてすりぬけて cleanup がされてるとばかり疑ってたんですが、子プロセスの１個でも終了した時点で tempfile モジュールが勝手に消してるってことなんですね。
tempfile.mkdtemp と os.rmtree にかえたところ発生しなくなりました